# Xposed as a system app

Tags: system-apps, xposed-framework, reformat

And by the course of the days, memory keeps stacking and stacking up on Android, I have the habit of restoring the phone after a while (even with root, SuperSU as system app). But now I have Xposed framework, and it is not a system app (but I can change that easily). Do Xposed framework keeps working when the phone is restored? (Assume that Xposed is a system app)

Comment: A factory reset will not touch the system partition/storage ... It specifically wipes the data partition/storage only ! ... Assuming that you have installed Xposed Framework, you will have a custom modified app_process in system/bin and even removing the Xposed application should still keep the framework active !  However you may need to allow the specific permissions with xposed !  Hypothetically you can remove root access and still use Xposed afterwards .. but due to the new Android Pay and Certified Device's change's, it may have difficulty working, as this could be a serious security issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xposed Installer is not necessarily a system app; however, Xposed framework itself , mainly `/system/bin/app_process`, is. If by "restore" you mean factory reset (wiping `/data`) then it will not go away.

Comment: Uh, I didn't know that they were different things. Thanks and btw if I make the Installer a system app, it will not be erased either?

Comment: Yup. Why you'd want to do that is beyond me, though.

Comment: Just because I don't wanna reinstall it (I even don't know if I still have apk)